# JSON ForEach in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, json, foreach

I have coded an url-shortener using Node.JS and saving in json-data. Now I'm coding an Web-Dashboard for my Team to manage the urls. I like to use `forEach`, because I can easily use it to add code to my html site for each entry. My problem: 
I have json data just like this:

```
    {
      "support": {
        "url": "https://this-is-the-url.end",
        "author": "Name of the Author"
      },
      "invite": {

      "url": "https://an-other-url.end",
      "author": "Name of the Author"
    },
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

and I dont know how to split it so I can use

```
Object.forEach(json => {
var author = json.author
var url = json.url

*add code to html code*

})
```

I already searched on Stackoverflow but i could not find something. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: forEach works on an array. If it is not an array, then you cannot use forEach. Please show a better example with more authors. Show us some of the ... you have now

Comment: Also you have author and support.author. Which of them do you want

Comment: oh i've made an mistake typing in the json data. now it should be better

Comment: It is not better, Please give an example with 3 sets of data if it is an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
Object.keys(bigJson).forEach(key => {
  const json = bigJson[key];
  const author = json.author;
});
```

*(Note that `bigJson` and `json` are not actual JSON strings, they're objects, but I wanted to keep OP's naming to avoid confusion at this point.)*

Comment: I'll try later on. Could be my problem if it is running for Each key...

Answer (score 0):

It might be like this:

```js
import json from '/some/path/to/urls.json';

Object.entries(([key, value]) => {
  doSthWith(key); // 'support', 'invite';
  doSthElseWith(value.url, value.author);
})
```